# How to display data from database in dataTable?

Tags: java, jsf, datatable

In my java web project I want to test how to display a list in a dataTable, I have a sample in which there is the display of that. I try to follow the sample  so I created a new xhtml page in which i copied the sample's dataTable, I added a new dataTable and I created a new bean called StatPanne.The bean of the sample is NaturePanneController. 
The problem is that the new dataTable is empty. I understand that the list returned by the new bean is empty but I don't know why, please, whould you help me.Thanks.

```
@Name("naturePanneController")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class NaturePanneController {
@In
EntityManager entityManager;
@In
@Out
NaturePanne naturePanne;

private Boolean edit = false;
private Integer paramid;

public Boolean getEdit() {
    return edit;
}

public Integer getParamid() {
    return paramid;
}

public void setParamid(Integer paramid) {
    this.paramid = paramid;
}

public void setEdit(Boolean edit) {
    this.edit = edit;
}

public List<NaturePanne> getNaturePanne() {
return entityManager.createQuery("select a from NaturePanne a")
            .getResultList();   
}


public void selectNP(NaturePanne np) {
    naturePanne = np;

}

public void supprimer() {
    if (naturePanne != null) {
        //if (nn != null) {
        Integer a = getParamid();
        NaturePanne np = entityManager.find(NaturePanne.class, a);
        entityManager.remove(np);
    }
}

public void ajouter(ActionEvent e) {
    entityManager.persist(naturePanne);
    naturePanne = new NaturePanne();
}


public void mettreajour() {

    if (getEdit() == true) {
        setEdit(false);
    } else {
        setEdit(true);
    }}}
```

My new bean StatPanne.java

```
@Name("statPanne")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class StatPanne {
@In
EntityManager entityManager;

@In
@Out
NaturePanne naturePanne;


private Boolean edit = false;
private Integer paramid;



public Boolean getEdit() {
    return edit;
}

public Integer getParamid() {
    return paramid;
}

public void setParamid(Integer paramid) {
    this.paramid = paramid;
}

public void setEdit(Boolean edit) {
    this.edit = edit;
}

 public List<NaturePanne> getNaturePanne() {
    return entityManager.createQuery("select a from NaturePanne a").getResultList();


}


public void selectNP(NaturePanne np) {
    naturePanne = np;
}

public void supprimer() {
if (naturePanne != null) {
    //if (nn != null) {
    Integer a = getParamid();
    NaturePanne np = entityManager.find(NaturePanne.class, a);
    entityManager.remove(np);
}
}

public void ajouter(ActionEvent e) {
entityManager.persist(naturePanne);
naturePanne = new NaturePanne();
}


 public void mettreajour() {

if (getEdit() == true) {
    setEdit(false);
} else {
    setEdit(true);}}}
```

My page xhtml which contains the two datatables

```
<!-- the new dataTable: empty table -->
<h:form>
<rich:dataTable   value="#{statPanne.naturePanne}" var="lp">
<h:column headerClass="headerleftfacet">
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="#{msg.nom_panne}" />
</f:facet> 
<h:outputText id="outtt" value="#{lp.lib_naturepanne}"/>      
</h:column>
</rich:dataTable>
</h:form>       


<!-- the old dataTable:works well -->
<h:form>
<rich:dataTable  var="panne" value="#{naturePanneController.naturePanne}">
<h:column headerClass="headerleftfacet">
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="#{msg.nom_panne}" />
</f:facet>
<h:outputText  value="#{panne.lib_naturepanne}"/>
</h:column>
</rich:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

The entity NaturePanne.java

```
@Entity
@Name("naturePanne")
@Scope(ScopeType.EVENT)
@AutoCreate
@Table(name = "naturepanne")
public class NaturePanne implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id_naturepanne;
private String lib_naturepanne;

//Getters/Setters
```

Comment: If the list returned from the database is empty, it is a pure database/jpa issue, not java-se jsf or datatable

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do you have any suggestion

Comment: @Kukeltje In your opinion,why my new dataTable is empty despite that I copied  the same bean ?

Comment: What kind of suggestion do you want? I'd suggest 'debug'

Answer (score 0):

Check the EntityManager configuration.
Enable show sql config in EMF settings as below.

Depending on what implementation you use..
for hibernate :
`<property name = "hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" />`
for jpa : 
`<property name="${filename}" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>`

THis way, you can see SQL it tries to execute, you can test this SQL in isolation to see if you actually have results from data store.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: In your opinion,why my new dataTable is empty despite that I copied the same bean ?